# Multiple database support for django-elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

We have a system where we are using a multi-database setup. E.g Multiple companies will have their own database.

Django database setup example:

```
{
   "default":{
      "ENGINE":"django.db.backends.postgresql",
      "NAME":"default"
   },
   "db_2":{
      "ENGINE":"django.db.backends.postgresql",
      "NAME":"db_2"
   }
}
```

Also, we have decided to use **Elasticsearch** with **Django Elasticsearch DSL**. But we wouldn't be able to index like our relational databases.

When I try to rebuild the index **Django Elasticsearch DSL** trying to index using only the default database.

How I can route different databases on a different index or something same scenario like our relational database.